# How to get and show images

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fetch and display images using the code below, but it is not working. What is wrong with my code?

```
dataList.getList = function(s_page,show_page){
        var haveData = null;
        $.post("jsoncars.php",{
            action:'list',
            page:s_page
        },function(response){
            if(response != null && response.data.length > 0){
                $(".pagination").removeClass("hidden");
                $(".show-list-data").removeClass("hidden");                     
      *.find("td:eq(0)").text(response.data[i].car_img).end()*//<---this images
```

Comment: put your code in  blocks by ctrl +k or surround single lines of code in ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dataList.getList = function(s_page,show_page){
    var haveData = null;
    $.post("jsoncars.php",{
        action:'list',
        page:s_page
    },function(response){
        if(response != null && response.data.length > 0){
            $(".pagination").removeClass("hidden");
            $(".show-list-data").removeClass("hidden");                     
  .find("td:eq(0) > img").attr("src","http://localhost/rentalcars/picup/"+response.data[i].ca_img).end()
```